# Unable to open .cd file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class-diagram

I have created a class diagram in visula studio 2010 and saved it on the desktop with a .cd extension. After restarting my system, when I try opening the file once again, I get this error... "Cannot open file. Class diagrams can only be added to projects that contain source code".

I tried opening the project associated with it but since I hadn't written the source code before I restarted the system, everytime I open the .cd extension Class Diagram, I'm not able to view the diagram I created but rather I get to see a diagram without any associations, methods, or attributes.

I tried googling it but couldn't get a satisfactory solution. Please help me to view the document as how I have created it. I need to include this diagram in a document.